# Primary domain rewrite for nginx works fine, but doesn't direct single pages

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-redirect

We just moved our website to a new domain, and the new website uses a totally different URL structure for all of the pages on the website.

For example, the old URL might look like: http://example.com/product/product-name/

The new URL would look like this: http://www.example2.com/product-p/product-name/pro-n.htm

Here's a snippet showing an example of what I'm working with:

```
server{

    location /product/product-name/ {
    rewrite ^/product/product-name/
    http://www.example2.com/product-p/product-name/pro.htm
    permanent;
    }

    server_name example.com www.example.com; 
    rewrite ^ $scheme://www.example2.com;

}
```

As it's working now, http://www.example.com redirects to http://www.example2.com just fine.

However, if you try to visit http://www.example.com/product/product-name/ doesn't redirect to http://www.example2.com/product-p/product-name/pro.htm, it simply redirects to the root domain http://www.example2.com

Does anyone know how we redirect the primary domain AND redirect single pages to their new page?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your global rewrite directive into a location container:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^ $scheme://www.example2.com;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Richard's answer is fine.

I would only notice that [`permanent`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) in the end of `rewrite` directive means `301` redirection, and such redirections are cached by all browsers, which can make it difficult to test. So while you are testing, I would recommend using `redirect` instead of `permanent`.

When you're done, put `permanent` back. Good luck!